# sql window function not giving me the right output

Tags: sql, presto

```
A     B   C   D
1pm   a   1   1
2pm   a   2   2
3pm   b   1   1
4pm   b   2   2
5pm   a   3   1
6pm   a   4   2
```

When I do `row_number() over (partition by B order by A) as C .`, I get the column C. How do I get column D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a group to the "adjacent" values.  One simple method is the difference of row numbers:

```
select a, b, 
       row_number() over (partition by b, (seqnum_a - seqnum_ab) order by a) as d
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by a) as seqnum_a,
             row_number() over (partition by b order by a) as seqnum_ab
      from t
     ) t;
```

The difference of row numbers is one solution to some types of gaps-and-islands problems (basically what you are asking for).  Why it works is a little tricky to explain.  I find that if someone sees the results of the subquery, they will usually get why the difference identifies the adjacent rows.